# How to set input fields on MySite -> Edit Details as disabled/enabled

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I want to forbid user’s on MySite to edit their details on MySite.

When they click the Edit My Profile Button it should show them an overview over their details but only specified input fields should be editable by them.

for example like  in this picture:

If its possible i want to set that by code, because the PersonalSite creation is handled by an EventReceiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found an answer by myself which fits my needs.

I'm getting the `UserProfile` of the User when creating his PersonalSite.

And then iterate through Properties which i have choosen and set the `IsUserEditable` Property to false on the `ProfileSubTypeProperty`

```
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
UserProfile profile = null;
profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(domainUserName);
List<string> props = GetPropertiesFromSetting();
foreach (string propName in props)
{
   profile[propName].ProfileSubtypeProperty.IsUserEditable = false;
}
```